# Is it possible to run Ubuntu on a Asus Padfone 2 at the moment?

Tags: tablet

Is it possible to run Ubuntu on a Asus Padfone 2 at the moment?

If possible please let me know how to make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
Supported devices are:

- Samsung Galaxy Nexus
- LG Nexus 4
- Asus Nexus 7
- Samsung Nexus 10

Maybe Padfone 2 will be in future.